# forcetk restapi broken in visualforce page (not in lighting container)

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, apexrest, forcetk

The following code was working fine until few months back, but now it is broken and giving an error as below:

```
    var params = { 'Type': 'Folders' };
    var forcetkClient = new forcetk.Client();
    forcetkClient.setSessionToken('{!$Api.Session_ID}');
    forcetkClient.apexrest('/helptips/Froala/get', function (data, status, xhr) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('ForcetK.data:', data);
    }, function (xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log("Request failed: ", xhr,  textStatus);
    }, 'GET', params);
```

> HTTP ERROR 400
>
> Problem accessing /services/proxy. Reason:
>
> ```
>    Unable to forward request due to: Stream closed
> ```

I'm sure I've not changed anything in the code (i've confirmed the same from the git).

Any thoughts/suggestions on what I should be checking to fix??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [forcetk in lightning:container](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217098/forcetk-in-lightningcontainer)

Comment: hey, this is in VF page .... and it was working fine.